# Using selectors in css to filter out certain elements

Tags: css, printing, css-selectors

I'm trying to get ride of the last column in each table EXCEPT for the last table on the page. Is there a way to do this in css?

Here is what I have, and it doesn't seem to be working...

```
table:not(:last-child) tr td:last-child {

}
```

If this can't be done in css, please just let me know. :)

Comment: This works as is, in chrome.  http://jsfiddle.net/SLjDU/

Comment: [Safari 5.1 as well](http://jsfiddle.net/SLjDU/1/). (Updated from last comment to make it easier to differentiate tables.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `table:not(:last-of-type)` instead, in case there are other elements *after* that last `table` in your page:

```
table:not(:last-of-type) tr td:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

It also depends on the browsers you're testing in. No version of IE older than 9 supports the pseudo-classes being used.

Comment: Ahh yes that may be a problem seeing as I need to program for at least IE7. Thanks you for the helpful information. :)